# Issue with Faker gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, faker

I installed Fabrication and Faker in my Rails 4 project

I created a fabrarication object:

```
Fabricator(:course) do
  title { Faker::Lorem.words(5) }
  description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(2) } 
end
```

And I'm calling the Faker object within my courses_controller_spec.rb test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CoursesController do
  describe "GET #show" do
    it "set @course" do
      course = Fabricate(:course)
      get :show, id: course.id
      expect(assigns(:course)).to eq(course)
    end
    it "renders the show template"
  end
end
```

But for some reason, the test failes at line 6:

```
course = Fabricate(:course)
```

the error message is:

```
Failure/Error: course = Fabricate(:course)
 TypeError:
   can't cast Array to string
```

Don't know exactly why this is failing. Has anyone experienced the same error message with Faker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return from `words(5)` is an array, not a string. You should do this:

```
title { Faker::Lorem.words(5).join(" ") }
```

Comment: Added another solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was available back then, but another solution would be to give it a sentence instead of a word:

From the repo

```
def sentence(word_count = 4, supplemental = false, random_words_to_add     = 6)
    words(word_count + rand(random_words_to_add.to_i).to_i, supplemental).join(' ').capitalize + '.'
end
```

So you could do:

```
Faker::Lorem.sentence(5, false, 0)
```